# Eloquent query where and condition OR where and different condition

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I need to create a query that searches for (first name = foo AND last name = bar) OR (first name = bar and last name = foo). This has been really frustrating to get working properly. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
$this->_records->where('first_name','LIKE', $params[0])->where('last_name', 'LIKE', $params[1])->orWhere('first_name','LIKE', $params[1])->where('last_name', 'LIKE', $params[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group them together like this:

```
$this
    ->_records()
    ->where(function ($query) use ($params) {
        return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', $params[0])
            ->where('last_name', 'LIKE', $params[1]);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($params) {
        return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', $params[1])
            ->where('last_name', 'LIKE', $params[0]);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query which allows to search on several fields.

```
$this->_records
     ->whereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%".$params."%' ")
     ->orWhereRaw("concat(last_name, ' ', first_name) like '%".$params."%' ")
     ->get();
```